# Summing Int of Range and blocking Range when maximum is reached

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying a script for a character generator of a RPG and want people to set their stats. These stats can go from 1 to 10 each. The user uses regular HTML ranges to set them. I'm summing these up until the user reaches 18 points overall. The issue here is, that I don't know how to stop the the rages to go up when 18 points are hit.
I'm summing the stats up like this:

```
<fieldset id="attribute" oninput="streight.value=parseInt(staerke.value);wisdom.value=parseInt(weisheit.value);agility.value=parseInt(geschick.value);APWert.value=parseInt(staerke.value)+parseInt(weisheit.value)+parseInt(geschick.value)+' / 36'">
                    <legend>Attribute</legend>
                        <label for="staerke">Stärke</label>
                        <input type="range" id="staerke" value="1" min="1" max="10">
                        <output name="streight" for="staerke">1</output>

                        <label for="weisheit">Weisheit</label>
                        <input type="range" id="weisheit" value="1" min="1" max="10">
                        <output name="wisdom" for="weisheit">1</output>

                        <label for="geschick">Geschick</label>
                        <input type="range" id="geschick" value="1" min="1" max="10">
                        <output name="agility" for="geschick">1</output>

                        <output name="APWert" id="APWert" for="ap">3 / 18</output>
</fieldset>
```

This is counting the values of the range-inputs, summing them up and showing them in the output without a page reload. But I have no idea how to stop the range-inputs when the maximum of 18 is reached.
I'd be really thankful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something were the validation runs each time the input of any of the three inputs is changed. It would look something like this:

**In HTML**

```
<input type="range" id="staerke" value="1" min="1" max="10" onchange ="value_changed()">
<input type="range" id="weisheit" value="1" min="1" max="10" onchange ="value_changed()">
<input type="range" id="geschick" value="1" min="1" max="10" onchange ="value_changed()">
```

**In JS**

```
function value_changed(){
   //pull in the three values
   var staerke_value = parseInt($("#staerke").val());
   var weisheit_value = parseInt($("#weisheit").val());
   var geschick_value = parseInt($("#geschick").val());

   if((staerke_value + weisheit_value + geschick_value ) > 18 ){
     //if you are out of the range alert the user
     alert("you messed up!");
   }
}
```

Comment: It looks so simple but somehow it just alerts all the time. Even when I just touch the range, the alert pops up.

Comment: so oninput should have been onchange ... that should be less annoying

Comment: I see the next issue is, that it doesn't sum up the values but concatenates

Comment: I was under the impression that range's .val() returned integers in jquery. But it is simple enough to fix it. just use parseInt()

Comment: After I while I found out why parseInt didn't work for me (just messed some stats up) and everything works fine! Thank you a lot!